# Non-locality of gravitational energy

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, energy-conservation, gravitational-waves, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Gravitational energy is non-local which is essentially because of the equivalence principle. The equivalence principle says that you can always transform your frame so that you feel like in a Minkowski space-time locally. Mathematically, there is no tensor-like definition for gravitational energy in General Relativity. All energy-momentum tensor for gravitational energy must be pseudo-tensor, namely frame-dependent tensor. About the non-locality of gravitational energy I have one question:

1. Where does the energy of gravitational waves come from which seems way local?

Comment: I don't think the energy density of gravitational waves is any less observer-dependent than the energy-density of electromagnetic waves. If string theory is a Lorentz-invariant theory, then it should reflect this fact.

Comment: First one: I think usually for gravitational waves one defines a certain region in space D which is much larger than the wavelength of a gravitational wave:
$D>>\lambda$ but at the same time define a region S which is much larger than D: $S>>D>>\lambda$. This way, one can define an average quantity for energy in the area D over some time scale and we can call it energy. The reason they do this is because for a local region (1 point) you can always transform back to minkowski metric. 
I guess you can have some 'energy' from the geodesic deviation equation as well (looking at oscillating masses)

Comment: Can't help with the second point :/

Comment: Hi @Wein Eld: I removed the string theory question. Please only ask one question per post, cf. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6833/2451) meta post.

Comment: @Otto Thanks for your comment. It seems that gravitational wave energy is not that local as I thought. It is like the tidal energy which is essentially non-local while looks like local?

Comment: @WeinEld Yeah somewhat like that. Take a large rubber sheet which is flat on average and put waves on it. It's evident that the waves carry energy when you look at the whole rubber sheet. If you're an observer affected by gravitational waves, however, and you're at rest, there's no way you can tell if you're being affected by a gravitational wave. When a gravitational wave goes past you, you wouldn't feel unless the wavelength is much smaller than your body.

Comment: @CuriousOne, I am sorry, I don't think your comment give the answer for the question about string theory.

Comment: It reflects on some fairly trivial aspects of the setup of your question, which is why it is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @CuriousOne ''If string theory is a Lorentz-invariant theory, then it should reflect this fact. '' First, Lorent-invariance can not explain the non-locality of gravitational energy. Second, It sounds like a reply kind of ''If general relativity is defined on a manifold, then it should not contain singularity.'' I asked how to implement it specifically, not a conclusion.

Comment: Lorentz invariance is sufficient to cause non-local wave-like phenomena. I think we can file that under "experimental fact", can't we? If string theory contains general relativity then you are done here. If it doesn't, then we don't have to ask about string theory any longer. In that case it's in the trash can, already.